# Is there a way to access a child view via a relative path from within an {{each}} block?

Tags: ember.js

[Reger this link](http://jsfiddle.net/adamlogic/8NhYX/).

This link provides the example of rendering a nested view using a relative path.

I want to do the same thing, but from within an `{{each}}` block.

[Refer this Example for {{each}}](http://jsfiddle.net/adamlogic/CrCaj/)

Since the scope has changed in the block, is it possible to get to view from there, or must I use an absolute path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my understanding after reading the source, the {{#each}} helper is a basic iterator that only knows about the array you pass it. So in your example the array App.projectController.content is all it has access to directly.

You'll need to use {{#collection}} for what you're trying to do or you need to use absolute paths within the {{#each}} helper. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/qw4pe/) using the {{#collection}} helper.

**EDIT (12/02/13)**

I have [updated the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/qw4pe/) to show two different ways to accomplish this using the each helper with the action helper.

Comment: That makes sense. I heard that the collection helper is deprecated, though, but I'm not sure why. Stuff like this doesn't seem possible without it.

Comment: Collection helper is slower than the each helper for large lists. But for something small (I'd think under 200 items or so) the collection helper should be fine.